# E4Rat vs Plymouth Splash Screen

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I'm currently running Linux Mint 10.  Since I have an nVidia graphics card, I installed the driver and used [this fix](http://idyllictux.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/lucidubuntu-10-04-high-resolution-plymouth-virtual-terminal-for-atinvidia-cards-with-proprietaryrestricted-driver/) to fix the Plymouth bootsplash afterward because it was in text-mode for the bootsplash.  I have since installed and configured [e4rat](http://sourceforge.net/projects/e4rat/) to cache files at boot.  It seems to have sped up things considerably, but has also re-broken my bootsplash.  The resolution is correct, and plymouth is running, but the splash doesn't show.

Is there a way to get Plymouth using the uvesafb driver AND play along with e4rat?

-Extra Notes-
I am using 64-bit Linux Mint.
My copy of e4rat is compiled from source because the prebuilt package was 32-bit only
My graphics card is nVidia 9800M GS (notebook)
The splash screen appears during shutdown as it did before.  It's only the boot splash that is affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show bootsplash, add this line to your grub.cfg kernel parameters:

```
plymouth:force-splash
```

For my system that results in something like the following:

```
... ro **plymouth:force-splash init=/sbin/e4rat-preload**
...
initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-28-generic
...
```

Comment: Modifying my /etc/default/burg file right now (alternate graphical grub-based bootloader).  Same as grub, just more graphical, so the conf file is the same.  I'll let you know if it works.